# Application of theorems 'about free groups'

Tags: soft-question, free-groups

What consequences have theorem

> Any nonzero subgroup of free group is free

or some another similar theorems?
P.S. especially not-group-theretic applications.

Comment: The axiom of choice for families of finite sets. At least when considering the theorem in $\sf ZF$.

Comment: "Non-zero" subgroup?? Now that's a strange wording....and unnecessary: **any** subgroup of a free group is free, up to and including the trivial  subgroup, if that was the meaning.